# Photoshop - loop to start from bottom layer of stack/ hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, photoshop

Is it possible to run a loop script to start from the bottom layer up of the layer stack? Currently, the script below will start from the top most layer inside a group layer.

```js
var layers = group.layers;

for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
  layers[i].visible = false;
}

for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
  layers[i].visible = true;

  var pngOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  pngOptions.compression = 9;
  var exportFile = new File(savePath + "/" + layers[i].name + ".png");
  doc.saveAs(exportFile, pngOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```

Comment: Just change ( reverse ) the for loop conditions to, `for( var i= layers.length -1; i >=0 ; i--)`

Comment:  It works. Thanks man. Now to understand what it means.

Comment: instead of starting from `0` as index, here we are starting with `last index` and then coming to down to `0`

Comment: i= layers.length -1; // " i equal to the number of layers -1 " I dont understand this part.

i >=0 // i is greater or equal 

i-- // decreace number in i

Comment: `i >=0 ; i--` : if `i` is greater than or equal to `0`, decrease `i` by `1`. The exact opposite of `i < layers.length; i++` (if `i` is smaller than `layers.length`, increase `i` by `1`